# How to fetch request data from flask post request

Tags: python, flask, twilio

I'm building a coinbase bot in python that uses twilio to fetch my coinbase portfolio, and send an SMS to my phone with the current balance. What I am trying, but struggling to do now, is to conduct coinbase transactions based on the message I send back to the twilio number.

For twilio to receive my messages, I had to set up a small flask server and funnel the environment to a public ngrok url, which I then attach in my twilio account settings as a webhook url to receive messages.

Here's my flask:

***msg_app.py***

```
from twilio.rest import Client as twilioClient
from flask import Flask, request, redirect
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse
from pyngrok import ngrok


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/sms", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sms_reply():
    """Fetch message response to extract order data"""
    body = request.values.get('Body', None)

    resp = MessagingResponse()

    resp.message('test')

    return str(resp)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Pretty much, I'll `cd` into the directory holding this script (msg_app.py), and run `msg_app.py` run to start the server. I'll then run `ngrok http 5000` (5000 being the local host port) in a different cmd prompt, to start the funnel.

If I sent a message on my phone to the Twilio number, like `'Hello'`, I'll get `test` back as a response, but how, in my bot script, can I get that `'Hello'` message, so I can then invoke logic based off the content of that message? Here's my bot, for example:

***coinbase_bot.py***

```
import dotenv
import selenium
import coinbase
import requests
from coinbase.wallet.client import Client
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import sys
import re
from twilio.rest import Client as twilioClient
from flask import Flask, request, redirect
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse
import msg_app
from msg_app import sms_reply


sys.path.insert(0, os.environ['USERPROFILE'])

dotenv_path = os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + '\prod.env'
load_dotenv(dotenv_path, override=True)

api_key = os.getenv('coinbase_api_key')
api_secret = os.getenv('coinbase_api_secret')

# TWILIO

account_sid = os.getenv('twilio_account_sid')
auth_token = os.getenv('twilio_auth_token')
twilio_number = os.getenv('twilio_number')

# Clients

coinbase_client = Client(api_key, api_secret)
twilio_client = twilioClient(account_sid, auth_token)

# user = coinbase_client.get_current_user()
accounts = coinbase_client.get_accounts()
currencies = coinbase_client.get_currencies()
id = accounts['data'][0]['id']

class Bot:

    def __init__(self, accounts):
        self.accounts = accounts
        self.account_id = self.accounts['data'][0]['id']
        # self.method_id =

    def get_current_price(self, ticker):

        for coin in accounts['data']:
            if coin['currency'] == ticker:
                value = "$" + str(coin['native_balance']['amount'])

        self.value = value

        return self.value

    def send_notification(self):

        price = self.get_current_price('LRC')

        self.message = twilio_client.messages.create(
            body='The price of your portfolio is currently: ' + str(price),
            from_=twilio_number,
            to='+1555555555')

    def fetch_payment_method(self):

        payment_method = coinbase_client.get_buys(self.account_id)
        self.method_id = payment_method[0]['payment_method']['id']
        # set up twilio, to end notification when price is below certain amount

    def execute_sales(self, account_id, amount, currency, method_id):

        coinbase_client.sell(account_id=account_id, amount=amount,
                             currency=currency, method_id=method_id)

    def receive(self, msg):

        self.ticker = "".join(re.findall(r'[A-Z]{3}', msg))
        self.amount_to_sell = "".join(re.findall(r'[0-9]', msg))

        b.execute_sales(account_id=self.account_id, currency=self.ticker,
                        amount=amount_to_sell, method_id=self.method_id)

        # based on SMS response, method executes trade
b = Bot(accounts)
```

I'd like to run the receive function to execute a sale based on message content. Can I do this? I was trying to extract the body content from the flask script like: `body = request.values.get('Body', None)` and somehow send this result back to the bot. But, since msg_app is like the server script, how can I call that script inside my bot, without messing up the server?

Maybe I should wrap the bot in a while loop, and put receive in a try/except clause?

Or, maybe I have limited understanding of how all this works.  Hope I was clear.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a Twilio client in the flask app. Read the following article, it has the necessary things covered to receive sms content.
https://www.twilio.com/blog/real-time-sms-dashboard-python-flask-twilio-sync

**msg_app.py**

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request
from twilio import twiml
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from twilio.rest import Client
from pyngrok import ngrok
load_dotenv()

# Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
# and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
auth_token = os.environ['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']

app = Flask(__name__)
twilio_client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

@app.route("/sms", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sms_reply():
    """Fetch message response to extract order data"""
    number = request.form['From'] 
    message_body = request.form['Body']
    resp = twiml.Response()
    resp.message('Hello {}, you said: {}'.format(number, message_body))
    return str(resp)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

#end snippet

Now we just need to point a phone number at our app.

Open the phone number configuration screen in your Twilio console. Scroll down to the “a message comes in” field. You should see something like configure with webhooks
Punch in the URL for our message route that was generated by ngrok. It should look something like http://your-ngrok-url.ngrok.io/sms.

Click save, then text your number to get a response!